# Creating Function using array_merge

Tags: php, arrays, function, array-merge

It is not checking is that the mentioned field is there or not. Both of the version

First Version:

```
$error = array();
$field_sets = array('username','password','fullname','repeatpass','email');
foreach($field_sets as $fieldname){
    if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] != 0)) {
        $error[] = $fieldname;
    }
}
```

Second Version:

```
(in the includes file)
function check_required_fields ($required_array){
    $error = array();
    foreach($required_array as $fieldname){
        if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] != 0)) { 
            $error[] = $fieldname;
        }
    }
    return $error;
}

In the Source File:
$error = array();
$required_field = array('username','password','fullname','repeatpass','email');
$error = array_merge($error , check_required_fields($required_field , $_POST));
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is, but one thing I do see is that you are not using the second argument passed to `check_required_fields`. It shouldn't matter, but it still looks funny.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I accidentally put `&&` in the logic. It should be `||` instead of `&&`.

```
          if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) || $_POST[$fieldname] != 0))
```